# snmpwalk is not showing all information required

Tags: linux, networking, debian, snmp

I am trying to collect the data from the server through SNMP.
snmpwalk does not return back any essential data as a web interface does, but I need to fetch that kind of data via SNMP.

```
snmpwalk -c public -v 1 <ip> .

iso.3.6.1.2.1.1.1.0 = STRING: "OCMF agent SNMP"
iso.3.6.1.2.1.1.2.0 = OID: iso.3.6.1.4.1.11606.0
iso.3.6.1.2.1.1.3.0 = Timeticks: (95236803) 11 days, 0:32:48.03
iso.3.6.1.2.1.1.4.0 = STRING: "helpdesk@pbn.com.au"
iso.3.6.1.2.1.1.5.0 = STRING: "Copyright(c)2004 Pacific Broadband Networks"
iso.3.6.1.2.1.1.6.0 = STRING: "8 Keith Campbell Court"
iso.3.6.1.2.1.1.7.0 = INTEGER: 0
iso.3.6.1.2.1.11.1.0 = Counter32: 6505
iso.3.6.1.2.1.11.2.0 = Counter32: 6580
iso.3.6.1.2.1.11.3.0 = Counter32: 127
iso.3.6.1.2.1.11.6.0 = Counter32: 41
iso.3.6.1.2.1.11.15.0 = Counter32: 225
iso.3.6.1.2.1.11.16.0 = Counter32: 6285
iso.3.6.1.2.1.11.17.0 = Counter32: 0
iso.3.6.1.2.1.11.18.0 = Counter32: 0
iso.3.6.1.2.1.11.19.0 = Counter32: 0
iso.3.6.1.2.1.11.25.0 = Counter32: 0
iso.3.6.1.2.1.11.26.0 = Counter32: 0
iso.3.6.1.2.1.11.27.0 = Counter32: 0
iso.3.6.1.2.1.11.28.0 = Counter32: 6516
iso.3.6.1.2.1.11.29.0 = Counter32: 75
iso.3.6.1.4.1.11606.1.1 = INTEGER: 1
iso.3.6.1.4.1.11606.1.2 = INTEGER: 255
iso.3.6.1.4.1.11606.1.3 = INTEGER: 0
iso.3.6.1.4.1.11606.1.4 = INTEGER: 0
iso.3.6.1.4.1.11606.1.5 = INTEGER: 0
iso.3.6.1.4.1.11606.1.6 = INTEGER: 1357399287
iso.3.6.1.4.1.11606.1.15 = INTEGER: 1357399287
End of MIB
```

and if I enable OID resolving in /etc/snmp/snmp.conf I get:

```
SNMPv2-MIB::sysDescr.0 = STRING: OCMF agent SNMP
SNMPv2-MIB::sysObjectID.0 = OID: SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.11606.0
DISMAN-EVENT-MIB::sysUpTimeInstance = Timeticks: (95258487) 11 days, 0:36:24.87
SNMPv2-MIB::sysContact.0 = STRING: helpdesk@pbn.com.au
SNMPv2-MIB::sysName.0 = STRING: Copyright(c)2004 Pacific Broadband Networks
SNMPv2-MIB::sysLocation.0 = STRING: 8 Keith Campbell Court
SNMPv2-MIB::sysServices.0 = INTEGER: 0
SNMPv2-MIB::snmpInPkts.0 = Counter32: 6534
SNMPv2-MIB::snmpOutPkts.0 = Counter32: 6609
SNMPv2-MIB::snmpInBadVersions.0 = Counter32: 127
SNMPv2-MIB::snmpInASNParseErrs.0 = Counter32: 41
SNMPv2-MIB::snmpInGetRequests.0 = Counter32: 225
SNMPv2-MIB::snmpInGetNexts.0 = Counter32: 6314
SNMPv2-MIB::snmpInSetRequests.0 = Counter32: 0
SNMPv2-MIB::snmpInGetResponses.0 = Counter32: 0
SNMPv2-MIB::snmpInTraps.0 = Counter32: 0
SNMPv2-MIB::snmpOutGetRequests.0 = Counter32: 0
SNMPv2-MIB::snmpOutGetNexts.0 = Counter32: 0
SNMPv2-MIB::snmpOutSetRequests.0 = Counter32: 0
SNMPv2-MIB::snmpOutGetResponses.0 = Counter32: 6545
SNMPv2-MIB::snmpOutTraps.0 = Counter32: 75
SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.11606.1.1 = INTEGER: 1
SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.11606.1.2 = INTEGER: 255
SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.11606.1.3 = INTEGER: 0
SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.11606.1.4 = INTEGER: 0
SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.11606.1.5 = INTEGER: 0
SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.11606.1.6 = INTEGER: 1357399287
SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.11606.1.15 = INTEGER: 1357399287
End of MIB
```

I would like to fetch the same set of parameter as available in web interface

6. 1.MTEMP 30C O
7. 1.LCUR 61mA O
8. 1.LPWR 09.9mW Z
9. 1.OMI 04.2% Z
10. 1.ERF 20.5dBmV O
11. 1.RFI 41.9dBmV O
12. 1.RFO 36.6dBmV Z
13. 1.LTEMP 31C O

Is this possible?

Comment: The snmpwalk dump that you've provided is just a snapshot of RFC1213 (mib-2) data. It is not the information you're interested in as it only contains data about network interfaces and common things like system information. You'll need to contact your vendor to get specific set of MIB files for this particular device. The data you'd like to retrieve is usually located in private enterprise specific branch of MIB tree.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will contact the the vendor for set of MIB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dump you've provided as a result of `snmpwalk` command is just a snapshot of `RFC1213 (mib-2)` data. And yes your assumptions are correct: It is not the information you're interested in as it only contains the set of data about network interfaces and common system information (`system` group of MIB-II). You'll need to contact your vendor to get specific set of MIB files for this particular device. Usually the target MIB files are available on vendor's web site in Download area. The data you'd like to retrieve is usually located in `private` enterprise specific branch of MIB tree.

From what I see the Enterprise OID 1.3.6.1.4.1.11606 belongs to **Pacific Broadband Networks (PBN)**.

Also I've found the definition for the root element of this MIB module:

```
PBN-ROOT DEFINITIONS ::= BEGIN

IMPORTS
     enterprises
          FROM RFC1155-SMI;

pbn  OBJECT IDENTIFIER ::= { enterprises 11606 }

END
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This device is old and I can not find any MIBs on website. I send them an email and now waiting for the response.
I hope they sent me needed MIBs.